# can we use azure data explorer function (for example series_decompose() ) locally or anywhere in python program

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-data-explorer, azureml-python-sdk

There is function in azure data explorer i.e. series_decompose() , so I need to use this function in my python program locally with data from sql

So can I do it, and if yes then how?

Comment: if the answer below helps, please accept it (see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top) to know why and how). If you still need more info, please add a comment elaborating what you're missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can run KQL functions when using Kusto (a.k.a. ADX or Azure Data Explorer), or another service that runs on top of Kusto, e.g. Azure Monitor, Sentinel etc.

Comment: i am not using kusto , i just need to use series_decompose() this function in my program . Apart from this i am not going to use anything from kusto or azure

Comment: series_decompose() is a Kusto function, that the Kusto engine can process. If you're not using Kusto, but something else, then you should look for an alternative in that language/product.